# ExtJs Grid startCollapsed when set to true, collapse all and expand all doesn't work

Tags: extjs

I am trying to add Collapse All and Expand All feature to my ExtJs grid which has grouping feature

I added a property called startCollapsed to true so that all the groups are collapsed when grid loads

After adding startCollapsed: true, to expand any group first time I have to double click on that group. So ExpandAll or Collapse All doesn't work. I did some research and got the below link for same issue but that did not work

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?208801

My Code below.

```
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Expand All',                    
                handler: function (event, target, owner, tool)
                {

                    var eFormsView = Ext.getCmp('gridId').getView();
                    var groupFeature = eFormsView.getFeature('groupSummary');                        

                    if (groupFeature.collapsedState['groupSummary'] === undefined && groupFeature.startCollapsed)
                    {
                        groupFeature.collapsedState['groupSummary'] = true;
                    }

                    grdItems = eFormsView.getEl().query('.x-grid-group-hd');
                    for(i=0;i<grdItems.length;i++)
                    {
                        var groupBody = Ext.fly(grdItems[i].nextSibling, '_grouping');
                        groupFeature.expand(groupBody);
                    }
```

Comment: You linked to a bug that was fixed in ExtJS 4.1.1 and didn't mention which version of the framework you use. There are certain versions of ExtJS where expandAll and collapseAll are completely bugged, including 6.0.0 and 6.0.1. So please specify which version you use.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am using 4.1.0 version